# Change avatar on Arqade

Tags: discussion

It might be easy for you guys, but I can't figure it out, how can I change my avatar (profile picture) on Arqade? Did I need to have enough reputation point to do this? I have tried to change it by clicking my name at the top but is doesn't seems to have any change avatar's option. Help me :/

Comment: Here: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/edit/95673

Comment: Questions about Arqade should be asked on [meta] instead.

Comment: @PrivatePansy - http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current works for any user that clicks the link :)

Answer (score 5):

You can change your profile picture here, you don't need any rep to do it.

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current

You have to click your profile picture in order to change it. Thanks for pointing it out, Timelord64.

Comment: might be worth noting that you have to click on the picture, as some users will miss that completely.